# Importing to trunk does not work Tortoise Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created the following Repository structure using VisualSVN

```
MyCompanyRepository
    Project1
        branches
        tags
        trunk
```

I copied the URL off of the trunk folder.  Then I went to my **c:\www\Project1** folder and right-clicked it and did TortoiseSVN | Import and the url was `https://ourserver/svn/MyCompanyRepository/Project1/trunk`

It added the files but my folder does not appear to be in source control.  I mean the files are there in the trunk on the server, however locally, I have no .svn anywhere.  So am I doing something wrong?  I get no flags showing that my folder is running under svn, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check out files from SVN repo to disk: Importing does not imply creation of a local working copy.

Comment: ah that's right!  I also noticed that in the checkout you need to erase the project name in the Checkout Directory path or it will create a new folder which is not what you want.

Comment: by default tortoise specifies the default directory in the checkout as C:\www\Project1\Project1 but you want just C:\www\Project1\ or else you'll end up with a folder C:\www\Project1\Project1 in your local drive as the checked-out/versioned folder.  You want your root folder C:\www\Project1\ to be versoined, not a newly created sub folder

Answer (score 1):

Importing does not automatically turn the directory you imported into what Subversion calls a working copy.  You need to either delete everything in c:\www\project1 and do a checkout, or do a checkout in an empty directory and copy everything over.

Answer (score 0):

The import doesn't create a checkout locally - you'll need to run Checkout from TortoiseSVN to get the files.